# PostgreSQl JDBC и русские буквы

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

jdbc драйвер отказывается принимать русские буквы и вместо них бросается вопросами.

Есть метод:

```
    Connection con;
Statement statem;
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/AgroService?useUnicode=true&charSet=UTF8";
String name = "postgres";
String password = "1234";
public void DBConnect () {

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loading success!");
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, password);
            System.out.println("Connected.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public int[] sizeDB(String nameTable) {
    int cRow, cColumn;
    int[] sizeDB = new int[2];
    try {
        String query = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM " + nameTable;

        statem = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultSet = statem.executeQuery(query);
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            String res = resultSet.getString(1);
            cRow = Integer.parseInt(res);
        } else cRow = 0;
        sizeDB[0] = cRow;

        query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='" + nameTable + "'";
        resultSet = statem.executeQuery(query);
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            String res = resultSet.getString(1);
            cColumn = Integer.parseInt(res);
        } else cColumn = 0;
        sizeDB[1] = cColumn;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sizeDB;
}
```

если во время выполнения в nameTable отправить tovar, то все будет нормально. Если же отправить "Товар", то получится это:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: отношение "?????" не существует
  Позиция: 23
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:562)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:406)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:286)
    at program.One.sizeDB(One.java:62)
    at program.One.main(One.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Кодировка БД - UTF8. Версия PostgreSQL 9.3, сам JDBC - postgresql-9.3-1103.jdbc41

P.S. Пробовал добавлять к url всякие "?characterEncoding=WIN1251&useUnicode=true" и т. д. но не помогло.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно уже и не надо, но всё же:

```
//Загружаем драйвер
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Properties info = new Properties();
info.setProperty("user",user);
info.setProperty("password",pass);
info.setProperty("useUnicode","true");
info.setProperty("characterEncoding","utf8");
//URL к базе состоит из протокола:подпротокола://[хоста]:[порта_СУБД]/[БД] и других_сведений
//Создаём соединение
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + host + "/" + name, info);
```